# Further Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

[image: See problem]

Does anyone knows how to do $12(ii)~?$ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write up your questions here, rather than attaching a link or a picture. Also, please explain what you have tried and are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

$s^2=2+4$sin$^2θ  +4$sin$θ$cos$θ=2+4$sin$^2θ  +2$sin$2θ  =2+4(1-$cos$2 θ )/2+2$sin$2θ  =2+2(1-$cos$2 θ )+2$sin$2 θ =4-(2/\sqrt{2})(-\sqrt{2}$cos$2θ +\sqrt{2}$sin$2θ )=4-(2/\sqrt{2})[(-2$cos$2θ )(\sqrt{2}/2)+(2$sin$2θ )(2/\sqrt{2})]=4-(2/\sqrt{2})(-2$cos$(2θ +π /4))=4-4/\sqrt{2}($cos$(2θ +π/4))$